# Javascript document.getElementById('id').innerText not working

Tags: javascript

I have written a code to track values and display in span tags, values tracking is working but display part not working(innerText, i also tried using value) can someone please help me, thank you

```
function goAndSetTotal() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    if (document.getElementById('gst').checked) {
        document.getElementById('subtotal').innerText = amount;
        document.getElementById('gst_box').innerText =  amount*10/100;
        document.getElementById('total').innerText = amount + (amount*10/100);

    } else {
        document.getElementById('subtotal').innerText = amount;
        document.getElementById('gst_box').innerText =  0;
        document.getElementById('total').innerText = amount;
    }

}
```

Comment: change innerText to innerHTML

Comment: what is subtotal ? its input tag of div or span

Comment: guess its case sensitive so its `innerHTML`

Comment: use `textContent` or `innerHTML`

Comment: if its input tag use .value

Comment: off-topic: `amount * 10 / 100` is equivalent to `amount / 10`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `innerHTML` instead like

```
document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML = amount;
```

Take a look at differences between them, let's say you have following html

```
<div id="Test"><b>InnerText and InnerHTML</b><div>
```

`innerHTML` gives  `<b>InnerText and InnerHTML</b>`

`innerText` gives `InnerText and InnerHTML`

For more details visit <kbd>[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

try to use `innerHTML`

```
function goAndSetTotal() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    if (document.getElementById('gst').checked) {
        document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML = amount;
        document.getElementById('gst_box').innerHTML  = amount*10/100;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML    = amount + (amount*10/100);

    } else {
        document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML = amount;
        document.getElementById('gst_box').innerHTML  = 0;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML    = amount;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try innerHTML instead
Or
Make sure your web page have elements with id attribute

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `.js` file should be at the end of the body tag.

Then it will work for sure  :).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that doing something like this does not work:

```js
var amountContainer = document.getElementById('subtotal');

amountContainer.innerHTML = amount;
```

So the answer to this is to do simply:

```js
document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML = amount;
```

I hope this helps someone.